# dplyrXdf tempfile issue

Tags: r, revolution-r

It appears that there is some issue creating the temporary file that backs `dplyrXdf`, any thoughts?

```
xdf='/mnt/saswork/testout.xdf'
xdf %>% group_by(factor_pair)
```

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :
>     no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"
>   xdf %>% dplyrXdf::tblSource() %>% group_by(factor_pair)
>   grouped_tbl_xdf Source
>   "/tmp/Rtmp0oFfIY/file5c6964534b5c.xdf"
>   fileSystem: 
>       fileSystemType: native
>   xdf %>% dplyrXdf::tblSource() %>% group_by(factor_pair) %>% summarise(blah=sum(pair_dist))
>   Error in rxLocateFileInternal(file, pathsToSearch, fileSystem, isOutFile = isOutFile,  : 
>     /tmp/Rtmp0oFfIY/file5c6955f5cf2a.xdf not found in paths .;

Working dir is: `/home/aak87`.

```
 list.files(tempdir())


[1] "file5c6934f5920f"                                                                           
[2] "libloc_188_f198c64896a74076.rds"                                                            
[3] "libloc_203_fe207b7ffd125d09.rds"                                                            
[4] "repos_http%3A%2F%2Fmran.revolutionanalytics.com%2Fsnapshot%2F2015-11-30%2Fsrc%2Fcontrib.rds"
[5] "tmp_dropbox"
```

Comment: As per @alizaidi's answer, you need to supply a _data source_ as the input to the pipeline, not a _file name_ (a character string).

Answer (score 2):

Could you try first making an `RxXdfData` object?

```
xdf <- RxXdfData('/mnt/saswork/testout.xdf')
xdf %>% group_by(factor_pair) %>% tally()
```

`dplyrXdf` will work best when called against `RxXdfData` objects since it'll find the right methods to use with that class.